# ASP.NET MVC - debugging a deployed app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

### Setup:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app, deployed on a remote server that I can access using remote desktop.

The files have been published to the server, so there is no source.

On the remote server, there is a copy of Visual Studio 2012 Express installed.

### Questions:

What is the best way to debug the app on the server?

My knee jerk reaction is to open the app with Visual Studio 2012 Express and, well, debug it.

But with all code compiled into .dll files, will I be able to debug anything?

So... What strategy would you recommend?

### Problems:

As the solution has been published, there is no project file or solution file.  So how do I create a solution file to allow me to open this solution?

Sorry if this sounds basic, my brain is dead.  Well, almost.  I can still type...

Comment: any chance to have the debug symbols on the server as well? *(the .pdb files that follow the .dll's)*. If **yes** you can attach the process to Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have access to -any- of the source, or do you just have access to what has been deployed in production?

Comment: I don't think you can attach to a process with the VS Express debugger.  I think you have to have Standard Edition or better.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you have the source code and the option to redeploy the application to production, but I would use a logging framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [nLog](http://nlog-project.org/) to add logging to your project and dump debug information either to the file system, the database, or even a UDP listener (check out [Log4View](http://www.log4view.com/home/) as an option).  It would take some time & effort to get it setup and deployed, but it could save you multiples of that time in future debugging situations.

Also, check out [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).  I have never used it but I have heard some pretty smart people rave about it.

This won't help you if you are limited to debugging the bits that are currently deployed to production, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that you have to use the Remote debugger built into Visual Studio Standard and higher versions.  This allows you to debug code on a remote machine from your local machine assuming you have the access to the remote computer to setup the services and have accounts that allow you to access that information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=VS.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.110).aspx